# What is an efficient way to generate CO2 electrochemically?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I would like to build a small carbon dioxide generator for experimental purposes. There are two requirements that are set in stone:

1. It has to be electrochemical. (Easy to switch on/off with electricity.)
2. It has to generate only one gaseous product, which is carbon dioxide. (No need to separate the gases, which might prove difficult.)

I have thought and tried using oxalic acid in a cell with a proton exchange membrane, which did not work. (And I have not figured out why so far.) I kept generating oxygen instead of carbon dioxide. Also the byproduct was hydrogen, which is problematic in my application, and the PEM is very fragile, so I could not build up any pressure. There are a few requirements, that are debatable. For example if a reactant or product is highly toxic or extremely expensive, that would possibly be a dealbreaker. Also it would be nice to be able to enclose the cell and build up a bit of pressure with carbon dioxide (only 1-2 bar).

Unfortunately researching this is rather difficult, since the main topic of research is binding carbon dioxide, which are 99.9% of the publications that pop up with the keywords I have searched for. Are there other things I could try? I have not tried a lot and I am already running out of ideas, but please bear with me, I am a theoretician and have not been in the lab for quite a long time.

Comment: Maybe not to your spec but you can readily buy dry ice - could you not keep some of it around in a deep freeze and use as-needed? It'll still sublimate but might be enough of a solution to get you on your way.

Comment: Carbon dioxide is easily liquefied at common temperatures. The *most* efficient way to release it from a cylinder is with a solenoid valve, which could use *far* less electricity than that required to produce the same amount by electrolysis. A solenoid *toggle* valve, e.g., https://www.smcpneumatics.com/MTV-3-M5.html , would use *no* power when static, i.e., open *or* closed, so would be more efficient, yet. Also, the raw material is pure CO2, so there is no waste to dispose, later.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Unfortunately that is not at all possible in my setup. While it would be relatively easy to get, storage really is the main problem there. I do not think the deep freeze would be sufficient for the timescales I had in mind and Dewars are really expensive (not even sure a Dewar would be much better than a styrofoam box in the deep freeze anyways).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am well aware of solenoid valves and CO2 in bottles. The ease of a solenoid valve comes with additional costs though. Pressure reducer, cylinder and all the other stuff (hell throw in a MFC for good measure, if I want to have any chance of accurate electronic control over the flow) quickly add up to an enormous cost. This question was not about how to get CO2 from a bottle, but how to generate it electrochemically.

Comment: You might want to provide additional constraining specs (budget etc). You will want to monitor how much CO2 you are releasing for instance, how are you doing this?

Comment: Buy a pellet gun that uses CO2 cartridges. Do not load pellets. Stick a tube into the nozzle of the gun (pistol) and from there into your apparatus. 12 gram CO2 cartridges (800 psi) are available. A gun shop can probably help you. Or you could put a balloon onto the pistol - bang, bang - detach the balloon and attach to your apparatus (not much over 1 atm then, tho.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kolbe electrolysis](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/kolbe-electrolysis.shtm) may be helpful to you. It is an electrochemical decarboxylation process with free radicals as intermediates, with applications in [syntheses of symmetric alkanes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1572665718303643).
[image: pic]

$\ce{H2}$ is generated as a side product on the cathode, but using aprotic solvents or a substance with a higher reduction potential than that of $\ce{H2}$, like $\ce{CuSO4}$, should fix this. Alternatively, as suggested by Poutnik, consider separating the compartments with a porous glass.

Comment: There is always possible to arrange  cathode + anode divided by salt bridge, diaphragm or porous glass to have both gases separated.